# Jquery - find input's parent div and change the div's child

Tags: jquery

Ajax "on-the-go" form. You click a field to send an ajax request to db. if successful - I'd like to change CSS of "dark" class. 
Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 dark">Gender</div>
        <div style="" class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"> Male</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"> Female</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

Logic is: when input (any) is clicked (and ajax response is received) - **to find the input's parent class ROW and change css (let's say - "color: green;") of the row's "dark" class.**

tried

```
$(this).closest(".dark").css('color', 'green');
```

with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dark div** is not a direct ancestors of your radio buttons. You need change it to:

```
$(this).closest(".row").find(".dark")
```

And because you are using this value inside a success function of an ajax call you cannot use directly the **this** keyword but you must save the value so after you can use it.

Instead of click event you can consider to use the change event.

An example:

```js
$(':radio').on('change', function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest(".row").find(".dark");
    var a = $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        row.css('color', 'green');
    })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 dark">Gender</div>
    <div style="" class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"> Male</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"> Female</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! of course - "find"....
regarding saving the value -  yeah, I know that. Thank you, gaetanoM!